# Obj-C NDEBUG issue in release app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The following code can be seen in the console for our dev AND production app:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    NSLog(@"log message");
#endif
```

Can anyone tell me how that is possible for a release app? We submitted the app using the Archive option in Xcode. And the Build Configuration is set to Release for the scheme that we're using.

I understand NDEBUG should be already be defined for the project. Is that correct or should I add it? Does the version of Xcode used to create the project matter?

Answer (score 3):

No matter how templates are set up now or in the past, you should always double-check all your settings. I don't believe that NDEBUG is defined by default for any configuration, so if you need this, you should check and make sure it's there and add it if it's not.

I believe the current version of Xcode defines NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS by default in the release configuration now, but again, you must need always check and verify any build settings you rely on after you create a new project.